# PreventDefault text selection context menu on mobile in browser

Tags: javascript

How to disable context text selection menu in browser? Is it possible?

This is how text-selection-menu is look like:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It very simple you just need to add **user-select** attribute in the css class. Here is a small code with ***p*** and ***span*** as tag as unselectable.

```css
p{
  user-select: none;
}

span{
  user-select:none;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
  <!--Full text is unselectable-->
  <p>This full text is unselectable</p>
  
  <!--A part of text is unselectable-->
  <div>Hello i am selectable but i am <span>unselectable.</span></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: nice solution :)

Comment: But i can't now select the text, i need to disable only native text-selection-menu

Comment: I am providing another answer for it. Hopefully you don't mind using javascript

Answer (score 3):

Another anwser on requirement of @OnengLar. Here is just a small trick to do that using js and html.

```js
function clicked(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  //Custom popup here
  alert('Right clicked me');//For now just showing an alert
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<span oncontextmenu="clicked(event);">Select me and see my different behaviour</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<span oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()">` seems works too, save one func

Answer (score -1):

The search function in your browser jsut searches for the specific string and then selects the text. You can use the `user-select` CSS-Property to change the behaviour of selected text. There is no other possibility for this. But you should check carefully if its compatible with your needed browsers and operating systems.

https://caniuse.com/?search=user-select

Answer (score -2):

You can disable the [`contextmenu`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/contextmenu_event) event so users can't interact with your page. You can enable this document wide or only on some elements.

```js
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => {
  event.preventDefault()
})
```

```html
<div>Some text that you can't right click or touch interact with</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, at least not in Chrome on Windows. I ran the snippet, touched the text, and it selected and gave the popup.