# How can I disable Edge mini menu on text selection in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, microsoft-edge

I am working on a React web app and have created a custom text selection menu. How can I programmatically disable the text selection mini menu in React? As you can see in the attached image, both the custom text selection menu and the built in Edge menu are showing.

Here is my site:
[image: Example of issue]

It is possible because Amazon was able to do it at https://read.amazon.com/. Here is a screenshot of Kindle in Edge: [image]

Comment: [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71649638/prevent-context-menu-in-edge-when-text-is-selected) [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68475833/5089567) Have you tried `preventDefault` on `contextmenu` event?

Comment: Yes I did. That disables the right-click menu, but not the text selection mini menu in edge.

Comment: I have not heard from you for a couple of days. Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think you could modify this feature programmatically for Edge, unless configuring it via browser settings is an option for you. Your "**text selection**" in Kindle Reader is not exactly the "**text selection**" Edge detects. You'll notice that you could only select a word-based phrase/sentence/paragraph in Kindle Reader, while in Edge normally you could select any alphabet you want. I think the key to your requirement is to avoid being detected as "**text selection**".